# full blog working fine but post-new.php throwing 404

Tags: 404-error, 500-internal-error

I'm getting a really weird error.

My entire blog works perfectly, except for the post-new.php page (Posts -> Add New).

I have debugging turned on via the config file but nothing shows in the debug.log or error_log files regarding post-new.php.

It simply re-directs to /500.shtml

Just to see what was up, I made a backup of post-new.php and just put "Hello world" in the file.  It still goes straight to /500.shtml.  So clearly it's not even getting to post-new.php

Btw, my blog was working perfectly yesterday but I had gone over my host's resource limit and initially even /wp-login was showing 500.shtml, but slowly the site came back online, but post-new is still not working.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error actually it is throwing ?? 404 or 500 ?

Comment: it is throwing 500

Comment: try checking newly created file has 0666 permission

Answer (score 1):

Internal server errors (error 500) are often caused by plugin or theme function conflicts, so if you have access to your admin panel, try deactivating all plugins. If you don’t have access to your admin panel, try manually resetting your plugins (no Dashboard access required). If that resolves the issue, reactivate each one individually until you find the cause.

If that does not resolve the issue, try switching to the Twenty Fifteen theme to rule-out a theme-specific issue. If you don’t have access to your admin panel, access your server via FTP or SFTP, navigate to `/wp-content/themes/` and rename the directory of your currently active theme. This will force the default theme to activate and hopefully rule-out a theme-specific issue.

If that does not resolve the issue, it’s possible that a `.htaccess` rule could be the source of the problem. To check for this, access your server via FTP or SFTP and rename the `.htaccess` file. If you can’t find a `.htaccess` file, make sure that you have set your FTP or SFTP client to view invisible files. Better go to ***Settings >> Permalinks*** and hit **Save Changes** button. It will regenerate your `.htaccess` file.

Hope this helps you.